# Advanced Settings for YouTube Live Streams

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm just getting started with the YouTube Live Streaming API (using Python), and things are working great except there's some advanced settings which don't seem to be exposed by the API (or at least not documented).  Does anyone know how to set the options highlighted in the screenshot below?

[Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjShd.png)

If you cannot see the image for whatever reason, some examples of settings I would like to set:

- Enable slow mode
- Change license to Creative Commons
- Uncheck "Promote on my channel page" option
- Uncheck "Make video statistics on the watch page publicly visible" option
- Check "Automatically make archive unlisted once the stream has ended."
- Uncheck "Allow comments"
- Uncheck "Users can view ratings for this video"
- Select "Optimize for interaction (low latency)"

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, there are existing properties that are already supported in [LiveBroadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) but not with [LiveStreams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams). Example is the use of [`contentDetails.enableLowLatency`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.enableLowLatency) which is supported, as of this writing, for LiveBroadcasts.

Comment: For this, you may want to check if there are relevant filed issues in the issue tracker. If there are, you may star an [existing issue/feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35178036). Otherwise, file a new feature request.

Comment: Also, you may regularly check [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/revision_history) to know the YouTube Live Streaming API changes and documentation updates.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if it is not documented, it is not available to us. But as @Teyam has said, you can put in a feature request.